# jquery armazenar valor durante loop e comparar com o proximo valor

Tags: jquery

Preciso comparar valores que vem em um objeto json e agrupar casos sejam iguais.
Ex: `{nome: andre,qt:"2"},{nome: andre,qt:"3"},{nome: marco,qt:"2"},{nome: marco,qt:"5"}`
preciso agrupar em objetos separados onde eu teria :
objeto 1 = {nome: andre,qt:"5"}
objeto 2 = {nome: marco,qt:"7"}

esta comparação teria que ser dentro de um loop .

Comment: Você pode criar um outro array para armazenar so os grupos

Comment: É possível q no looping seja feita a comparação dos valores e após criar os objetos separados?

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma (veja comentários no código):

Nesta primeira parte, eu crio objetos com os nomes diferentes (ex., `objeto_andre`, `obj_marcos` etc.) e somo os valores em `qt` para o mesmo nome:

```
var temp = []; // array temporária para guardar os nomes
for(var item of obj){
   var novo_obj = "objeto_"+item.nome; // nome do novo objeto

   if(!window[novo_obj]){
      window[novo_obj] = {nome: item.nome, qt: item.qt}; // se não existe, cria
      temp.push(item.nome);
   }else{
      var q = parseInt(item.qt);
      window[novo_obj].qt = (parseInt(window[novo_obj].qt)+q).toString(); // se existe, soma o valor
   }
}
```

Esta segunda parte é apenas para "renomear" os objetos criados:

De `objeto_andre` para `objeto1`

De `objeto_marcos` para `objeto2`...

```
// criar cópia dos objeto para objeto1, objeto2 etc...
for(var o in temp){
   var nome = temp[o];
   window["objeto"+ (parseInt(o)+1)] = window["objeto_"+nome];
   delete window["objeto_"+nome]; // deleto o objeto com o nome original
}
```

O resultado fica como nesta imagem, separados por nomes e com os valores somados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Em funcionamento:**

```js
var obj = [
   {nome: "andre", qt: "2"},
   {nome: "andre", qt: "3"},
   {nome: "marco", qt: "2"},
   {nome: "marco", qt: "5"},
   {nome: "paulo", qt: "11"},
   {nome: "andre", qt: "1"}
];

var temp = []; // array temporária para guardar os nomes
for(var item of obj){
   var novo_obj = "objeto_"+item.nome; // nome do novo objeto
   
   if(!window[novo_obj]){
      window[novo_obj] = {nome: item.nome, qt: item.qt}; // se não existe, cria
      temp.push(item.nome);
   }else{
      var q = parseInt(item.qt);
      window[novo_obj].qt = (parseInt(window[novo_obj].qt)+q).toString(); // se existe, soma o valor
   }
}

// criar cópia dos objeto para objeto1, objeto2 etc...
for(var o in temp){
   var nome = temp[o];
   window["objeto"+ (parseInt(o)+1)] = window["objeto_"+nome];
   delete window["objeto_"+nome]; // deleto o objeto com o nome original
}

console.log("Objeto 1", objeto1);
console.log("Objeto 2", objeto2);
console.log("Objeto 3", objeto3);
```

> Levando em consideração que os nomes não possuem espaços, acentos ou
>   caracteres especiais. Se houver essa possibilidade, será preciso
>   chamar uma outra função que remova esses caracteres.